# Problem with keyboard event in ag-grid with react-select as a popup custom cell editor

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-select, ag-grid-react

I want to use react-select as a custom cell editor for ag-grid

Here is the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sunset-uq0bk)

You can download the source [here](http://www.filedropper.com/sandbox2)

```
npm install
npm start
```

I've removed all the css so it looks so plain, but it still does the job.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "ag-grid-community": "20.1.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "20.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.16",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "ajv": "6.9.1",
    "prettier": "1.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Grid from './app/AgGrid'

const colDefs = [
    {
        headerName              : "Test",
        field                   : "test",       
        editor                  : "manyToOne",
        editable                : true,
        suppressKeyboardEvent   : function suppressEnter(params) {
            let KEY_ENTER = 13;
            let KEY_LEFT = 37;
            let KEY_UP = 38;
            let KEY_RIGHT = 39;
            let KEY_DOWN = 40;
            var event = params.event;
            var key = event.which;
            var editingKeys = [KEY_LEFT, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN, KEY_ENTER];
            var suppress = params.editing && editingKeys.indexOf(key) >= 0;
            console.log("suppress "+suppress);
            return suppress;
        },
        cellEditor              : "reactSelectCellEditor",
    },
]

ReactDOM.render(
<Grid
    readOnly={false}
    field={null}
    columnDefs={colDefs}
    editable={true}
    editingMode={null}
    rowData={[]}
/>
,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

AgGrid.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css'
import ReactSelectCellEditor from './ReactSelectCellEditor'

class Grid extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            columnDefs  : props.columnDefs,
            rowData     : [],
            isFormOpen  : false,
            editedData  : {
                data        : [],
                rowIndex    : null,
                columns     : []
            },
            frameworkComponents:{
                'reactSelectCellEditor': ReactSelectCellEditor,
            },
        }
    }

    updateRowData = (newData,index) => {
        var unsavedData = this.state.rowData.map((row,i)=>{
            if (i === index) {
                return newData
            }
            else{
                return row
            }
        })
        this.setState({rowData:unsavedData})
    }

    onGridReady = params => {       
    }

    createData = () => {
        let fields = this.state.columnDefs.map(column=>{
            return column.field
        })
        let newData = {}
        fields.map(field=>{
            if (field !== "id") {
                newData[field] = ""
            }           
        })
        newData["delete"] = false
        this.setState({rowData:[...this.state.rowData,newData]})
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({isFormOpen:!this.state.isFormOpen})
    }

    setEditedData = (data) => {
        console.log("editedData",data)
        this.setState({editedData:data})
    }


    render() {
        var defaultColDef = {
            editable:this.state.editable,
            sortable:false
        }

        var initColDefs = this.state.columnDefs.map(colDef=>{
            return {
                ...colDef,
                cellEditorParams:{
                    ...colDef.cellEditorParams,
                }
            }
        })

        var renderedColumnDefs = []
        if (this.props.editingMode === "inline") {
            renderedColumnDefs = [
                ...initColDefs
            ]
        }
        else if (this.props.readOnly) {
            renderedColumnDefs = [...initColDefs]
        }
        else{
            defaultColDef = {
                editable:false,
                sortable:false
            }
            renderedColumnDefs = [
                ...initColDefs,
            ]
        }
        var renderedRowData = []
        this.state.rowData.map(row=>{
            if (row.delete !== true) {
                renderedRowData.push(row)
            }
        })
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <AgGridReact
                    defaultColDef                   = {defaultColDef}
                    columnDefs                      = {renderedColumnDefs}
                    rowData                         = {renderedRowData}
                    onGridReady                     = {this.onGridReady}
                    onCellValueChanged              = {this.handleChange}
                    frameworkComponents             = {this.state.frameworkComponents}
                    singleClickEdit                 = {true}
                    stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus   = {true}
                    reactNext={true}
                />
                <div className="addButton" style={{padding:'5px', border: '1px solid black'}} onClick={()=>this.createData()}>Add</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    } 
}

export default Grid
```

And ReactSelectCellEditor.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CreatableSelect  from "react-select/lib/Creatable"
import { components } from 'react-select'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'red', label: 'Red' },
    { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue' },
    { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow' }
]

class ReactSelectCellEditor extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value : null
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    handleCreateOption = (inputValue:any) => {
    }

    handleChange(selected){
        this.setState({
            value : selected.value
        })
    }

    afterGuiAttached(param) {
        let self = this;
        this.Ref.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            // let key = event.which || event.keyCode
            // if (key === 37 || key === 38 || key === 39 || key === 40 || key === 13) {
            //     event.stopPropagation();
            //     console.log("onKeyDown "+key);
            // }
        });
        this.SelectRef.focus()
    }

    formatCreate = (inputValue) => {
        return (<p> Add: {inputValue}</p>); 
    };

    isPopup(){
        return true
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.state.value
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref = { ref => { this.Ref = ref }} style={{width: '200px'}}> 
                <CreatableSelect
                    onChange                = {this.handleChange}
                    options                 = {colourOptions}
                    formatCreateLabel       = {this.formatCreate}
                    createOptionPosition    = {"first"}
                    ref                     = { ref => { this.SelectRef = ref }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ReactSelectCellEditor
```

As you can see, a simple bare bone combined implementation between ag-grid and **popped up** (not in cell) react-select.

It works fine, except the default navigation key event of ag-grid hinders react-select from working flawlessly.

Now I've read about the solutions to this here in [ag-grid documentation of keyboard navigation while editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#keyboard-navigation-while-editing)

Here is the thing:

1. Firstly, I have tried solution 1 which is to stop event propagation of my custom cell editor. It works, but strangely **although** I stop the event bubbling in the **container** of react-select, not the react-select itself, as you can see from the commented out script in ReactSelectCellEditor.js, somehow React Select Key Event also stops executing. I don't know why react select event which is a child element of the div stops executing when I stop the event propagation in the parent element. Isn't the event supposed to bubble up from child to parent not the other way around? So first solution is a no go.
2. As for the second solution the one that is strange is ag-grid itself. As the documentation says, ag-grid allows us to intercept the key event by defining a function for suppressKeyboardEvent from the column definition. It works if the editing mode is **not** popup. But in my case, I use the popup mode, and in popup mode I find the suppressKeyboardEvent isn't triggered while editing, it isn't even called at all.

Now I'm in a deadlock. In the first solution the react-select behaves weirdly and in the second one it is the ag-grid that behaves weirdly. How do I solve this?

### Additional find

After searching through the internet it looks like React Select uses `SyntheticKeyboardEvent` which, if I'm not wrong, executes AFTER events have already gone through a first capture/bubbling cycle across the DOM tree. So if I stop the propagation `SyntheticKeyboardEvent` won't be triggered. But if I don't stop the propagation ag-grid which uses the native event listener will trigger its default navigation function and kill the react-select component. Now is this it for me? A dead end?

Comment: Can you setup a StackBlitz?

Comment: @AvinKavish I haven't tried that, is it necessary? You can download my code here.

Comment: Yeah but with a local copy it's hard for us to have a discussion plus I have to setup a dev environment. If you upload I'll do my best.

Comment: @AvinKavish it keeps saying installing dependencies to no end...

Comment: do you have a link to whatever that is setup?

Comment: Aight I have it setup

Comment: Here's the online setup: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sunset-uq0bk People dont have time to setup environment on their own and moreover its also generally not safe to download untrusted files on people's computer. Thus code setup should be made on online editors to replicate the example and then ask for recommendations / solutions from others which would likely get more views and faster solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me warn you this solution is a hack and an anti pattern. As you have stated react select uses SyntheticKeyboardEvent and it waits until the native event goes through the cycle across the DOM tree. But there is a way for you to call react select functionalities by modifying the code which will allow you to access the methods of react select component from other component which is why this is an anti pattern solution.

1. Remove `suppressKeyboardEvent` from colDef
2. Make a copy of `CreatableSelect` component from the node_modules/react-select/src/Creatable.js
3. Add these lines to the copied component to get access through onRef

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.onRef(this)
   }
   componentWillUnmount() {
      this.props.onRef(undefined)
   }
   ```
4. Pass the control methods of react select by defining these in the copy

   ```
   focusOption(param) {
      this.select.focusOption(param);
   }
   selectOption(param) {
      this.select.selectOption(param);
   }
   ```
5. Then when you render the component add `onRef = { ref => { this.SelectRef = ref }}`
6. Now you will be able to call these to simulate the control before you stop the propagation

   ```
   this.SelectRef.focusOption('up');
   this.SelectRef.focusOption('down');
   ```
7. You can gain access to react select's states by writing a method like this

   ```
   focusedOption() {
      return this.select.state.focusedOption;
   }
   ```
8. Complete the rest of the simulation by referencing to node_modules/react-select/src/Select.js line 1142

Comment: Wow, I've never thought of calling react-select functionalities before stopping the propagation, this might work! Dirty solution, but desperate times call for desperate measures, so I thank you!